# Oracle query to convert a value with brackets to negitive number

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a string column that has the values like below

```
Column A
(9167)
1042
21463
9979
(26351)
```

I need the output like below -

```
Output
-9167
1042
21463
9979
-26351
```

I need to trim the brackets and replace that with '-' Symbol by using update statement. Is there a way we can do it with a query?

Comment: I would expect to find someone having asked something similar to this. Have you tried anything like this, `translate(t.val,'\(\)','-')`?

Comment: Hi patrick - Looks like translate syntax is removing the braces but it's not adding '-' to the  value.

Comment: yes, I did not need to escape characters (first mistake) and for this requirement, I needed to map a - for the starting parenthesis as Alex indicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
with demo (column_a) as
     ( select '(9167)' from dual union all
       select '1042' from dual union all
       select '21463' from dual union all
       select '9979' from dual union all
       select '(26351)' from dual )
select column_a
     , case
           when trim(column_a) like '(%)' then
               to_number(regexp_replace(column_a,'[()]')) * -1
           else to_number(column_a)
       end as result
from   demo;

COLUMN_A     RESULT
-------- ----------
(9167)        -9167
1042           1042
21463         21463
9979           9979
(26351)      -26351
```

Comment: Hi William, Thank you. The datatype for both the input and output is varchar. While I try to execute the query I am getting an error saying inconsistent datatype: expected number got char

Comment: It works for me. Please add [a complete test case that reproduces the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have just changed `to_number(regexp_replace(column_a,'[()]')) * -1` to `to_char(to_number(regexp_replace(NET_SALES_AMT,'[()]')) * -1)` and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: You'll also need to change `else to_number(column_a)` to `else column_a`.

Answer (score 1):

**Use Translate 'from characters', 'to characters'**

As the user guide states, "TRANSLATE lets you make several single-character, one-to-one substitutions in one operation."

One just maps the replacement characters as follows:

from: `()`

to: `-`

where the 1st from character `(` is mapped to the 1st to character `-`

where the 2nd from character `)` is mapped to the 2nd to character, which doesn't exist so is null

```
   SCOTT@db>WITH tst AS (
  2      SELECT
  3          '(9167)' val FROM
  4          dual
  5          union all
  6          select 
  7  '1042' val FROM
  8          dual
  9          union all
 10          select 
 11  '21463' val FROM
 12          dual
 13          union all
 14          select 
 15  '9979' val FROM
 16          dual
 17          union all
 18          select 
 19  '(26351)' val
 20      FROM
 21          dual
 22  ) SELECT
 23      translate(t.val,'()','-')
 24    FROM
 25      tst t;

TRANSLA
-------
-9167  
1042   
21463  
9979   
-26351
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  I was in a hurry to leave and did not cross my t's and dot my i's.